# Entity Framework complex search function

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using `Entity Framework` with a `SQL Express database` and now I have to make a search function to find users based on a value typed in a textbox, where the end user just can type in everything he wants (like Google)

What is the best way to create a search function for this. The input should search all columns.

So for example, I have 4 columns. `firstname`,`lastname`,`address`,`emailaddress`.

When someone types in the searchbox `foo`, all columns need to be searched for everything that contains `foo`.

So I thought I just could do something like

```
context.Users.Where(u => 
  u.Firstname.Contains('foo') || 
  u.Lastname.Contains('foo') || 
  u.Address.Contains('foo') || 
  u.EmailAddress.Contains('foo')
);
```

But... The end user may also type in `foo bar`. And then the space in the search value becomes an `and` requirement. So all columns should be searched and for example `firstname` might be `foo` and `lastname` can be `bar`.

I think this is to complex for a Linq query?

Maybe I should create a search index and combine all columns into the search index like:

`[userId] [indexedValue]` where `indexedValue` is [`firstname + " "+ lastname + " "+ address +" " + emailaddress`].

Then first split the search value based on spaces and then search for columns that have all words in the search value. Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

The first step with any project is managing expectation. Find the minimum viable solution for the business' need and develop that. Expand on it as the business value is proven. Providing a really flexible and intelligent-feeling search capability would of course make the business happy, but it can often not do what they expect it to do, or perform to a standard that they need, where a simpler solution would do what they need, be simpler to develop and execute faster.

If this represents the minimum viable solution and you want to "and" conditions based on spaces:

```
public IQueryable<User> SearchUser(string criteria)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
        return new List<User>().AsQueryable();

    var criteriaValues = criteria.Split(' ');
    var query = context.Users.AsQueryable();

    foreach(var value in criteriaValues)
    {
        query = query.Where(u => 
            || u.Firstname.Contains(value)
            || u.Lastname.Contains(value)  
            || u.Address.Contains(value)
            || u.EmailAddress.Contains(value));
    }

    return query;
}
```

The trouble with trying to index the combined values is that there is no guarantee that for a value like "foo bar" that "foo" represents a first name and "bar" represents a last name, or that "foo" represents a complete vs. partial value.  You'd also want to consider stripping out commas and other punctuation as someone might type "smith, john"

When it comes to searching it might pay to perform a bit more of a pattern match to detect what the user might be searching for. For instance a single word like "smith" might search an exact match for first name or last name and display results. If there were no matches then perform a `Contains` search. If it contains 2 words then a First & last name match search assuming "first last" vs. "last, first" If the value has an "@" symbol, default to an e-mail address search, if it starts with a number, then an address search.   Each detected search option could have a first pass search (expecting more exact values) then a 2nd pass more broad search assumption if it comes back empty. There could be even 3rd and 4th pass searches available with broader checks. When results are presented there could be a "more results..." button provided to trigger a 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. pass search if the returned results didn't return what the user was expecting.

The idea being when it comes to searching: Try to perform the most typical, narrow expected search and allow the user to broaden the search if they so desire. The goal would be to try and "hit" the most relevant results early, helping mold how users enter their criteria, and then tuning to better perform based on user feedback rather than try and write queries to return as many possible hits as possible. The goal is to help users find what they are looking for on the first page of results. Either way, building a useful search will add complexity of leverage new 3rd party libraries. First determine if that capability is really required.